# Give a non-trivial direct sum decomposition for the generalized Prufer $$-group $H_{\omega+1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, p-groups

We know that the generalized Prüfer $p$ -group $H_{\omega+1}$ is a group having the following generators and relations respectively

$$X=\{a_0,a_1,a_2,\ldots\},~~~ \{pa_0=0, p^na_n=a_0,~ \text{for all}~ n\geq 1\}.$$

Also, we know that $H_{\omega+1}$ is not an indecomposable gruop (moreover, it is not a direct sum of indecomposable groups).

${\bf Question}.$ Give a non-trivial direct sum decomposition $H_{\omega+1}=A\oplus B$ of $H_{\omega+1}$.

Comment: For example $\langle a_1 - p a_2 \rangle \oplus \langle a_2, a_3, \dots\rangle$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is the direct summand  $<a_2, a_3,...>$ isomorphic   with the group itself?

Comment: Good question. The element $a_1$ has order $p^2$ and no $p$th root. I think there is no such element in $\langle a_2, a_3, \dots\rangle$.